# Tweetstream: warning: kqueue is not supported on this platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, eventmachine

I'm using ruby on rails 4.1.8 and ruby 2.2.0 and the god gem to monitor my tweetstream process (using the tweetstream gem). But for the last few days its just been giving the message below.

"warning: kqueue is not supported on this platform"

This is all i get in my logs. Usually it displays each tweet info as they come, now its just this. I dont think i even touched the code in the file itself.  I've no idea how to fix it.

Its ok on our other servers, so i assume the problem is in the code itself.

Comment: apparenly its just a warning message so im ok. And i was just reading from the wrong log file  :/

Answer (score 0):

Kqueue is a bsd/Mac system notifier, it is typically used to inform programs when system level events occur like "new data is ready on socket" or "file contents has changed". This error message implies you are using a Linux or Windows system, which have they're own notification systems, e.g., Linux can use epoll. You might to update your gemfile to fix this warning

Comment: yeah thanks for confirming that. after i googled it i only found BSD so i was like ???